# Struggling implementing Search bar filter with watcher in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, search, filter, vuejs2

I am currently doing a Vue Application that should display all countries from the restcountries.com API and the User should be able to search countries with the searchbar.

I tried to solve this with a watcher method that filters through the array, but everytime I type in something in the input field, all the Items disappear.

Here is the App.vue Code with the watcher:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>List of all Countries</h1>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="search" class="rounded-md shadow py-1 px-2" placeholder="Search for a country ...">
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center container mx-auto w-full">
      <CountryCard :filtered="filtered" :countries="countries"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from "axios";
import CountryCard from '@/components/CountryCard.vue';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    CountryCard,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      filtered: [],
      countries: [],
    }
  },
  watch: {
    search() {
      this.filtered = this.countries.filter(country => {
      country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getAllCountries() {
      let res = await axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all");
      this.countries = res.data;
      this.filtered = [...this.countries];
      console.log(this.countries);
    },
    
  },
  created () {
    this.getAllCountries();
  },
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.custom-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 25px rgba(9, 9, 12, 0.1);
}
</style>
```

And here is the CardList Component:

```
<template>
    <div class="grid md:grid-cols-4 gap-4 place-items-center">
        <div v-for="c of this.filtered" :key="c.name.common" class="flex flex-col border rounded-md my-4 shadow-md w-9/12 h-92">
            <img class="w-full h-44 object-cover object-center rounded-t-md" :src="c.flags.svg" :alt="c.flags.alt">
            <div class="px-4">
                <p class="font-bold mt-4"> {{ c.name.common }} </p>
                <div class="my-4 text-left">
                    <p><b>Population:</b> {{ c.population.toLocaleString("pt-PT") }}</p>
                    <p><b>Capital:</b> {{showCapital(c)}}</p>
                    <p><b>Region:</b> {{ c.region }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            filtered: {
                type: Array
            },
        },
        methods: {
            showCapital(country) {
                if (!country.capital) return "No Capital specified";
                return country.capital[0];
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

If anyone can help me, I would really appreciate it! I am a bit stuck on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in your `.filter()`, so the filter function returns undefined and all countries are filtered out.

Change

```
this.filtered = this.countries.filter(country => {
  country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
})
```

to

```
this.filtered = this.countries.filter(country => {
  return country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
})
```

or

```
this.filtered = this.countries.filter(country =>
  country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
)
```

(no curly braces around the arrow function body)

As a suggestion, you can use a computed property instead of the watcher. That way, you have it all in one place.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      countries: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filtered(){
      const search = this.search.toLowerCase()
      return this.countries.filter(country => {
        return country.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(search);
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getAllCountries() {
      this.countries = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all").then(r => r.json());
    },
    
  },
  created () {
    this.getAllCountries();
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
    <div>
      <input type="text" v-model="search">
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="country in filtered" :key="country.name.official">{{ country.name.common }}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.10/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It is always the small mistakes... Thank you so much for your help!!